# Get user profile from TFS REST API using credentials with RestSharp

Tags: rest, restsharp, azure-devops-rest-api

```
 var client = new RestClient("https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/profile/profiles/me?api-version=1.0");
 var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
 var authenHeader = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",
                    Convert.ToBase64String(
                    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                    string.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password))));
 request.AddHeader("Authorization", authenHeader.ToString());
 request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
 IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Response :

```
StatusCode: NonAuthoritativeInformation, 
Content-Type: text/html; 
.
.
```

Or this request can use only personal access token to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use [OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=vsts) with the profiles API, it doesn't support basic auth.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the token will be expired in 3600s and you'll need to refresh it.

Comment: But after time out ,why I still can access with that token?

Comment: If a user's access token expires, you can use the refresh token acquired in the authorization flow to get a new access token. Check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=vsts#refresh-an-expired-access-token